# Compile MPI with Clang but using a wrapper around a different compiler

Tags: c, macos, mpi, homebrew, mpich

How safe is it to compile MPI using one compiler like the clang for MacOS but when compiling your application/code you use a mpi wrapper a around icc or gcc.
Reason for this question is because installing mpi with homebrew comes compiled with clang  however I want to use either icc or gcc

Comment: if you are using `C` and not `Fortran` that might work. Worst case scenario is `clang` generated library will have some dependencies on the `clang` runtime`, and you will need to manually link with it if you build your app with an other compiler.

Comment: What about c++?

Comment: The C++ bindings were removed from the MPI standard more than a decade ago, so I am going to dodge the question by suggesting you modernize your code (if needed) and stop using them.

Comment: when I install mpi, I have a wrapper like mpicpc or mpig++ are they not wrappers around c++ compilers. How else would you compile your c++ code?#

Comment: You obviously need these wrappers and C++ compilers to build your C++ apps. My point is your C++ apps should use the MPI C bindings (or other C++ abstractions such as Boost.MPI) instead of the removed MPI C++ bindings.

Comment: Last time I checked boost.mpi, it looked very outdated. I need like MPI >3.0, so is the solution to write MPI C functions that are called from my c++ program?

Comment: After some search it does look like writing c functions is the best way forward if I need new MPI features, like shared memory communication etc.

Comment: Another question I am facing, If mixing the two. I can compile my c code using gcc and the main application using g++, but how do I link my whole application. I normally would use g++, but now not sure with MPI since I would be using MPI wrappers, and I need to avoid using mpic++

Comment: Use `mpic++` or manually figure out what it is doing automagically so you can do it manually.

Comment: Are you referring to using mpic++ to link the application. You said earlier not to use MPI c++ bindings. Am I not doing that by using mpic++ for the linkage?

Comment: MPI C++ bindings are an API (e.g. `MPI::Init()`) and are different than C++ compiler wrappers (e.g. `mpic++`). Avoid the former and use the latter.

Comment: gotcha... So infact I can use mpic++ for compiling my entire application both c and c++ code. Great thanks for your clearification.